# Background color spreads/covers outer div when applied to inner div

Tags: css, html, background-color

I have a `div` followed by another `div`

```
<div class="myclass">
  <div>Some Data</div>
</div>
```

and the class content like

```
.myclass div {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px 16px;
}
```

Here `background-color` is not only applied to `inner div` but also to the `outer div`.

Shouldn't it apply to the inner div only?
Are there any other possible ways?

I am not able to specify class to `inner div` as it is dynamically generated by other api..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `padding` to the outer `div`:

http://jsfiddle.net/xCedS/

```
.myclass {
    padding: 4px 16px;
}
.myclass div {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

---

Original answer that ended up working for the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6520122/1

Comment: *(I just completely changed my answer)*

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried both your answers, bt didnt work.. As in you current answer, the outer div gets colored, I want it in the inner div.

Comment: @user549757 - Can you post what you're seeing to http://jsfiddle.net/ and/or show us a demo of your project? thirtydot's answer works as you've described wanting. It's possible something else is interfering or you have an error somewhere that's causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks, your previous answer did the trick.. Though you may be finding this answer more promising, pl post the previous answer as optional, may help the future readers :)

Comment: @user549757: I added a link to the original answer in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is correct for what you want to do. The issue you have is in the way the sizes on the two divs is calculated.

Unless you have any other content inside `div.myclass`, its size will be set by the div inside it - basically, the inner div completely fills the outer div.

You could try adding:

```
.myclass {padding:16px;}
```

to see the difference - it will put space between the two divs.